# image upload api imgur return 400

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use Imgur API to upload image from my react project.

I first made the authorization step which returns a token, my id...But when I try to use the API request after receiving the authorization, I've got an error 400.

> createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400

```json
{"data":{"error":"Authentication required","request":"\/3\/image","method":"GET"},"success":false,"status":401}
```

Here is my request

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        var encoded = base64.encode(file[0].path)
        console.log("value encoded", encoded)
        axios('https://api.imgur.com/3/image', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': "Client-ID MY_PERSONAL_ID"
            },
            data: {
                'image': encoded
            }        
        })
    }
```

In this link you can find the request for the image upload from imgur.
[Imgur Request](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#de179b6a-3eda-4406-a8d7-1fb06c17cb9c)

Moreover, on the Imgur documentation, it says:

> Status Code: 400
> This error indicates that a required parameter is missing or a parameter has a value that is out of bounds or otherwise incorrect. This status code is also returned when image uploads fail due to images that are corrupt or do not meet the format requirements.

But I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Your error seems to be 401, not 400. I am not sure this is a React.js question. I would recommend removing react tag and adding javascript. Also, make sure that your client ID is correct. Try testing the call through Apps like Postman or Insomniaso you know there isn't anything wrong with your credentials first.